# indent beetwen key & value

Tags: python, regex

i would like to edit the same spacing between passwords and descriptions in dictionaryy with regex. It looks like this now:

```
ADRIAN,     Latin given name Adrianus or Hadrianus,
ADRIAN,                             a city in the U.S. state of Georgia,
ADRIAN, an unincorporated community in Rock Creek Township, Hancock County, Illinois,
```

and should look like this:

```
ADRIAN,     Latin given name Adrianus or Hadrianus,
ADRIAN,     a city in the U.S. state of Georgia,
ADRIAN,     an unincorporated community in Rock Creek Township, Hancock County, Illinois,
```

I tried with:

```
import re

text = '''
ADRIAN,     Latin given name Adrianus or Hadrianus,
ADRIAN,                             a city in the U.S. state of Georgia,
ADRIAN, an unincorporated community in Rock Creek Township, Hancock County, Illinois,
'''
```

p = re.compile("[^A-Z][,]$\t{4}(a-z)")
for line in text:
print(line)

and get result NONE or Process finished with exit code 0

Comment: I have an idea :D 2 seconds

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works: https://regex101.com/r/EgOLMv/1

```
import re

regex = r"([A-Z].+?,)\s+(.*)"

test_str = ("ADRIAN,     Latin given name Adrianus or Hadrianus,\n"
    "ADRIAN,                             a city in the U.S. state of Georgia,\n"
    "ADRIAN, an unincorporated community in Rock Creek Township, Hancock County, Illinois,")

subst = "\\1\\t\\2"

# You can manually specify the number of replacements by changing the 4th argument
result = re.sub(regex, subst, test_str, 0, re.MULTILINE)

if result:
    print (result)

# Note: for Python 2.7 compatibility, use ur"" to prefix the regex and u"" to prefix the test string and substitution.
```

Comment: Thank you, but with your solution I didn't got what I was expecting - the same spacing between key and value

Comment: well you could replace `\\t` with 4 hardcoded spaces, and that will produce the 4 spaces you need.. I just put `tab` there for convenience. The code produces same spacing as you can see in the working example in the link (bottom of the page)

Comment: Than you Ron, but I am absolutely beginer. Can you be so kind to write me a code which will enable 4 or 8 spaces.

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/EgOLMv/2 this produces 4 spaces, you can modify the line `subst = ` to add more spaces

Comment: Works perfectly. Thank you Ron!

Answer (score 0):

```
import re


text = """
ADRIAN,     Latin given name Adrianus or Hadrianus,
ADRIAN,                             a city in the U.S. state of Georgia,
ADRIAN, an unincorporated community in Rock Creek Township, Hancock County, Illinois,
"""
new_text = re.sub(r"(?<=ADRIAN,)\s+", "\t\t", text)
print(new_text)
```

### Output:

```
ADRIAN,     Latin given name Adrianus or Hadrianus,
ADRIAN,     a city in the U.S. state of Georgia,
ADRIAN,     an unincorporated community in Rock Creek Township, Hancock County, Illinois,
```

Comment: Thank you for your solution, but the problem is that the dictionary has about 160.000 keys and not just ADRIAN.

Comment: @BorisMilevoj does they all start with capital letters?

Comment: Yes It starts. Capital letter and than explenation.

Answer (score 0):

Ok 2 seconds became 20 minutes and I now have an idea for you. You don't even have to import regex :D

```
text = '''
ADRIAN,     Latin given name Adrianus or Hadrianus,
ADRIAN,                             a city in the U.S. state of Georgia,
ADRIAN, an unincorporated community in Rock Creek Township, Hancock County, Illinois,
'''
# Split all lines
arr             = text.split('\n')

# Remove empty strings (cleaning)
arr[:]          = [x for x in arr if x]

# Split on first comma.
for i in range(len(arr)):
    arr[i]      = arr[i].split(',', 1)
    arr[i][1]   = arr[i][1].strip()
```

With this implementation you can even go so far to make a dict with the keyword ADRIAN which has a value of type list which will contain all the related strings :D

Hope it was helpfull, have a nice day :)

#### EDIT:

I couldn't resist so I made a simple function that takes your string and returns a dictionary:

```
def parseDictionary(text):
    dictionary = {}
    arr             = text.split('\n')
    arr[:]          = [x for x in arr if x]
    for i in range(len(arr)):
        arr[i]      = arr[i].split(',', 1)
        arr[i][1]   = arr[i][1].strip()
    for i in arr:
        if i[0] in dictionary:
            dictionary[i[0]].append(i[1])
        else:
            dictionary[i[0]] = [i[1]]
    return dictionary
```

Comment: Than you Mama, but I couldn't resolve the problem with your kind effort. I am absolute beginer in coding and you function looks fine but my dictionary remain unresolved. Dictionary has about 160.000 words and it is very boring manualy write spacing.

Comment: Can you send me a big chunk of the dictionary then I will try again :) I like your project :D

Comment: Or maybe what you want is just the word, a tab and then the explanation. Even though a dictionary is more useful if you should digitalize it :)

Comment: I will change the function so it returns what you asked for :)

Answer (score 0):

So i personally like my other answer better :D But this one is closer to what you asked so you will get that one as well. :-)

```
text = '''
ADRIAN,     Latin given name Adrianus or Hadrianus,
ADRIAN,                             a city in the U.S. state of Georgia,
ADRIAN, an unincorporated community in Rock Creek Township, Hancock County, Illinois,
'''

def parseDictionary(text):
    dictionary      = ''
    arr             = text.split('\n')
    arr[:]          = [x for x in arr if x]
    for i in range(len(arr)):
        arr[i]      = arr[i].split(',', 1)
        arr[i][1]   = arr[i][1].strip()
        arr[i]      = arr[i][0] + '\t' + arr[i][1]
        dictionary += arr[i] + '\n'
    return dictionary

print(parseDictionary(text))
```

This one will work for words which is about the same length as ADRIAN, but when they get a lot longer or shorter then the tab will not fit all the way. Maybe you can improve it in the future :-)

I hope it was helpful.

And if you want more help with this project then please let me know. I like it, you could make many things with that dictionary, maybe a search function or something else :-)

Comment: Where can I send you a larger chunk of dictionary

Comment: It is working. I would like to increase the blank spaces between word and explanation to let say 4 blank spaces (Tab)

Comment: OK. I made it. I put 4 '\t' and it works. Than you very much

Comment: If you want to then send me the whole thing or a chunk to martin@maartensson.email then I can clean the data and save it as a JSON object and maybe create a small application that lets you search words and shows you the meaning in a nice view. :)